# Declaring dynamic variables inside for loop (C#)

Tags: c#

I have a task when I type for example 2 in the console then I am supposed to parse the next two lines of strings. I am giving you a clear example:

```
2
J 1 1 1 1
B 0 0 0 1
```

So when i do a for loop like this and when I console write it only shows me the 2nd basilisk(B 0 0 0 1):

```
string basilisk;
        int basilisk1D = 0;
        int basilisk2D = 0;
        int basilisk3D = 0;
        int basilisk4D = 0;
        string basiliskName = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBasilisks; i++)
        {
            basilisk = Console.ReadLine();
            var splittedBasilisk = basilisk.Split(' ');
            basiliskName = splittedBasilisk[0];
            basilisk1D = int.Parse(splittedBasilisk[1]);
            basilisk2D = int.Parse(splittedBasilisk[2]);
            basilisk3D = int.Parse(splittedBasilisk[3]);
            basilisk4D = int.Parse(splittedBasilisk[4]);               
        }
```

It erases me the first line and only put the data of the second basilisk so can I put in the for loop `i` in the name of the variables to make them unique for each of basilisk or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put eight integers and two strings into four `int` variables and one `string` variable. You need store the results in some sort of a collection.

First, create a class to store row data:

```
class Basilisk {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Num1 {get;set;}
    public string Num2 {get;set;}
    public string Num3 {get;set;}
    public string Num4 {get;set;}
}
```

Since you know right away how many rows you want, you can use arrays:

```
var basilisks = new Basilisk[numberOfBasilisks];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBasilisks; i++) {
    basilisks[i] = new Basilisk();
    var str = Console.ReadLine();
    var splittedBasilisk = str.Split(' ');
    basilisks[i].Name = splittedBasilisk[0];
    basilisks[i].Num1 = int.Parse(splittedBasilisk[1]);
    basilisks[i].Num2 = int.Parse(splittedBasilisk[2]);
    basilisks[i].Num3 = int.Parse(splittedBasilisk[3]);
    basilisks[i].Num4 = int.Parse(splittedBasilisk[4]);               
}
```

You can also use collections, depending on whether or not you have progressed to using lists in your coursework.